# How to pass user input as key value or variable from Html to express js to mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, user-input

I want to take the value that the user enters and pass that as the key value is this even possible? So where it says /hand-hold?handhold=userinput I want user input to be what the user types each time.

any help on this is greatly appreciated.

app.component.ts

```
setHandHold(val){this.http.patch('http://localhost:3000/api/simulation/hand-hold?handhold=userinput', {
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    }
```

app.component.html

```
      <label class="h3-responsive white-text"> Enter Handhold Value: </label>
  <br>
  <div id= "handholds">
  <input type="text" id = "handhold"  value="">
  <script>
    var val = "test";
    document.getElementById("handhold").value = val;
</script>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Submit" (click)= "setHandHold(val)">
  <br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a variable inside `${}`,  and Javascript will interpret the value. E.g.

```
const a = 'a';
console.log(`${a}b`); // ab
```

Applying it to your situation, you can patch dynamically as follows:

```
setHandHold(val){
    this.http.patch(`http://localhost:3000/api/simulation/hand-hold?handhold=${val}`, {
})
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
}
```

Note that you need to enclose your string inside a set of `'s instead of quotation marks.